# Set a specific value in input field when unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

We have table input to get morning & evening timing for user.

if user has to enter morning time, he has to check the checkbox. if it's unchecked it's blurred and he cannot fill value in it.

when it's unchecked, default value for time1 & time2 should be "00:00".

Same goes for evening timing.

Please suggest how to do so.

```html
<table border="1"">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">User Timing</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Morning</td>
    <td><input name="morning" type="checkbox" id="set_val1" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="time" name="time1" min="" class="timing" value="<?php echo $time1; ?>" placeholder="" required>
    to
    <input type="time" name="time2" min="" class="timing" value="<?php echo $time2; ?>" placeholder="" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Evening</td>
    <td><input name="evening" type="checkbox" id="set_val2" value="00:00"></td>
    <td><input type="time" name="time3" min="" class="timing" value="<?php echo $time3; ?>" placeholder="" required>
    to
    <input type="time" name="time4" min="" class="timing" value="<?php echo $time4; ?>" placeholder=""required></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not how it works; SO isn't a free coding service. You're supposed to do research. Handling clicks and blurring elements is extremely basic DOM manipulation, and you can find loads of tutorials for that.

Comment: I did, but it's confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".timing1").prop( "disabled", true); 
$(".timing2").prop( "disabled", true); 
$("#set_val1").click(function(){

  if($(this).prop("checked")==true)
  {
    $(".timing1").prop( "disabled", false); 
  }
  else{
    $(".timing1").prop( "disabled", true); 
  }

});

$("#set_val2").click(function(){

  if($(this).prop("checked")==true)
  {
    $(".timing2").prop( "disabled", false); 
  }
  else{
    $(".timing2").prop( "disabled", true); 
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1"">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">User Timing</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Morning</td>
    <td><input name="morning" type="checkbox" id="set_val1" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="time" name="time1" min="" class="timing1" value="00:00" placeholder="" required>
      to
    <input type="time" name="time2" min="" class="timing1" value="00:00" placeholder="" required >
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Evening</td>
    <td><input name="evening" type="checkbox" id="set_val2" value="00:00"></td>
    <td><input type="time" name="time3" min="" class="timing2" value="00:00" placeholder="" required>
      to
    <input type="time" name="time4" min="" class="timing2" value="00:00" placeholder=""required></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```